# My function isn't working

Tags: java

Hi I've got an error I cant find the answer help pls.

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Window extends Canvas {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -240840600533728354L;

  public Window(int width, int height, String title) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(Game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Game.start();

  }

}
```

This is the one that is not working I will include the file that is working at the bottom

It comes up with "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method start() from the type Game" on line 24.

And that game cannot be resolved to a variable on line 22.

I have included all of my files pls help.

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7580815534084638412L;

  public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

  public Game() {
    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!", this);
  }

  public synchronized void start() {

  }
  public void run() {

  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Game();
  }
}
```

Also line 22 is also buggy on this file
It comes up with error "The constructor Window(int, int, String, Game) is undefined"

Does anyone know how to fix this???

Comment: If it helps im using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gir2R7G9ws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Game` class - you need to instantiate an object of that class and use it.

Instead of doing:

```
frame.add(Game);
frame.setVisible(true);
Game.start();
```

Do:

```
Game game = new Game();
frame.add(game);
frame.setVisible(true);
game.start();
```

---

As for the other problem, the class `Window` doesn't have a constructor that can be applied for the call:

```
new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!", this);
```

There is only one constructor that accepts:

```
Window(int width, int height, String title)
```

So if you'll change your call to the Window's constructor and remove `this` as the last argument:

```
new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!);
```

I believe you should be good.

Comment: @LiamBoreback "no" refers to what exactly ? When you try to call `Game.start()` you're trying to invoke an instance method using the class object - that cannot work. Only static methods can be invoked like that and `start()` is not static.

Comment: What about the other problem @alfasin
because the "new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!", this);" line isn't working either it just says "The constructor Window(int, int, String, Game) is undefined"

Comment: @LiamBoreback the answer was updated to include the second issue.

Comment: Now the problems are coming up in the console it's saying at com.tutorial.Main.Game/Window.<init>(Game/Window.java:12/21) @alfasin

Comment: @LiamBoreback new problem == new question ;) and when you post the new question don't forget to post the relevant code, the full stacktrace/error description and show which line in the code triggers it.

Comment: Pls I can't post another question @alfasin